# Access denied to RAID disk after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, windows-10

I have 3ware hardware RAID 5. It all was working fine with Win7.

Today I upgraded to Windows 10, now the drive is no longer accessible:

```
Drive X:\ is not accessible.

Access denied
```

The drive is just showing up as 0 bytes.

- Permissions are set correctly
- I already took ownership using the UI as well as `takeown /f X:\*`
- I already reset permissions using `icacls X:\* /L  /Q /C /RESET`
- I updated my 3ware drivers
- I ran `explorer` as administrator

Still no luck. From the output of `takeown` I know that the drive is readable, since it listed all the directories it contains.

Any help is very much appreciated! Please just don't tell me to take ownership, I already did it 3 times.

The drive is shared and ABE is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 equivalent drivers are not allowing the proper drivers to install and take precedent. Lets start with the following steps to correct this:

1. To ensure changes to the driver do not occur without your knowledge, open the Control Panel (right-click Start button and select Control Panel)
2. Navigate to System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
3. Click Hardware tab > Device Installation Settings and select No, let me choose what to do option
4. Select Never install driver software from Windows Update
5. Next. Press the Windows key‌ Windows logo key+X and choose Device Manager
6. In Device Manager, navigate to RAID Controllers
7. Right click on the universal RAID driver and choose uninstall
8. Ensure the delete the driver software for this device is checked
9. Re-install the appropriate 3ware RAID drivers
10. Reboot the computer on installation completion

Even though you have downloaded the 2ware RAID drivers prior, the universal driver would still take precedent. Following this procedure would remove the universal driver and ensure only you are able to update the 3ware RAID driver in future.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not to be a problem with the driver, see "From the output of `takeown` I know that the drive is readable"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it;

- My user is in the group "Administrators"
- "Administrators" had full access to the drive
- No permissions were listed for "Users"
- I added "Users" and gave it read access - now I was able to access the drive

This makes no sense to me, but it works. Explanation appreciated.

Comment: After I turned my local windows account into a microsoft account, it worked with the previous permissions